# Rosewill RC-212 and Fedora 15

Tags: linux, fedora, raid

I recently bought a Rosewill RC-212 and configured it in the BIOS for RAID0.  Windows 7 recognizes the array without any extra drivers and installed to it without problems.

I installed Fedora 15 on a separate hard drive, however, it does NOT recognize the RAID array and instead shows them as separate hard drives with invalid header information.

Has anyone tried Fedora and the RC-212 or can steer me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a [fake RAID](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/RAID#Firmware.2Fdriver-based_RAID) card.

While there may be drivers out there to make it do the same thing it does under Windows, you'd be better off just using [Linux's software RAID](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Software-RAID-0.4x-HOWTO.html). It'll perform at least as well, maybe better due to the tight inteegration between the MD subsystem and the kernel buffer cache.